# How to get some specific HTTP headers using Guzzle 6 not downloading the file?

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, guzzle, guzzle6

I want to fetch some specific HTTP headers of a file like

```
Content-Type
Content-Length
```

before downloading the actual file. How can I retrieve them? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the HTTP method HEAD. This only retrieves the headers, but does not load the actual contents. Something like this will probably do the trick

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client->request('HEAD', 'http://httpbin.org/get');
```